# How to make one row based on last date in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Is there a simple way to just get Last `claimStatus`, last `Coverage` based on last `TransactionDate` in one row and have sum of `moneyvalue`.

```
declare @ClaimsTable table 
                     (
                          Claimantid int,  
                          ClaimStatus varchar(50), 
                          Coverage varchar(50), 
                          TransactionDate date, 
                          moneyvalue money
                     )

insert into @ClaimsTable 
values (1111, 'Closed','BI', '2018-09-28',  1500),
       (1111, 'Open','BI', '2018-09-18',  300),
       (1111, 'Closed','PD', '2018-01-30',  800),
       (1111, 'Open','PD', '2018-09-13',  500),
        (2222, 'Closed','PD', '2018-04-08',  200),
        (2222, 'Open','PD', '2018-04-10',  100)

select * from @ClaimsTable
```

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Is any identity column in your table?

Comment: Your sample data with the corresponding result is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with aggregation. Something like this.

```
select c.Claimantid
    , min(c.ClaimStatus)
    , Max(c.TransactionDate)
    , sum(c.moneyvalue)
from @ClaimsTable c
group by c.Claimantid
order by c.Claimantid
```

Comment: Thank you . But I forgot one important variable. Sorry about that. I modified the question.

Comment: So add coverage to the above query. You could use MAX easily based on the sample data.

Comment: There are cases when it can be Closed and then opened again. So it needs to be by  last TransactionDate. Sorry, I should have made better sample

Comment: Then can you make better sample data and desired output? I am not 100% sure what you want as this keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement

> Last claimStatus, last Coverage based on last TransactionDate in one row and have sum of moneyvalue

You can achieve it by 2 steps

1. Get `MAX(TransactionDate)` and `SUM(moneyvalue)` with each `Claimantid` accordingly.
2. Update `ClaimStatus`, `Coverage` based on `TransactionDate`.

```
    ;WITH cte_tempData AS( -- Step 1
         SELECT Claimantid,
                MAX(TransactionDate) TransactionDate, 
                SUM(moneyvalue) moneyvalue
         FROM ClaimsTable
         GROUP BY Claimantid, ClaimStatus
    ) -- Step 2
    SELECT t.Claimantid, c.ClaimStatus, c.Coverage, t.TransactionDate, t.moneyvalue
    FROM ClaimsTable c
    INNER JOIN cte_tempData t ON c.TransactionDate = t.TransactionDate
    ORDER BY t.Claimantid
```

Live demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc1e2e66c1090b899719e42872541c31)

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Serdia

Comment: Your output doesn't match with OP expected output as he need Coverage BI & PD for Claimantid 1111.